# How to use images and videos for compositing in Blender?

Tags: compositing-nodes, import

My question is about compositing....

I'm really new to Blender but I just noticed that it has a compositing system and that's great. Is there any way to import an image or video that I have already rendered in Maya into Blender for compositing? For example, can I import an image into the *Render Layers* in the *Compositing* window or can I only import images that have been rendered directly in Blender?

I've tried importing an image directly into the layer window, but then when I add settings for the composition, they don't get added to the image layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bou can't use the *View Layer* node as it manages the Blender scene.

But you can create an *Input > Image*, load your image, render, if you create an *Output > Viewer* and enable *Background* you'll see the image in the background of your *Compositor* window:

[image]

If I put a *Filter > Blur* node:

[image]

Comment: hello @moonboots does that give me the ability to add compositing option like in this video ? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jhTPI6QJQNg, because i tired that but that the only 2 option on the image layer are just alpha and depth, and in the video the guy is allowed to add noise image, denoising, etc.. etc..

Comment: Oh ok no you can't play with mist and so on as the image that you load is not your scene

Comment: could you link me a video that explain how can i still properly compose an image from maya if possible at all? and sorry another question does that also include animations ?

Comment: You can load an image or movie in the Image node, then put whatever node you want after that, like a Fliter > Blur for example if you want to blur your image. But you can't use the Mist or Cryptomatte options as they completely depend on the objects that are in your scene

Comment: alright so instead of having the option directly on the image layer like they are in the render layer, i just have to add them 1 by one with a new node each time. since the image/animation was not rendered in blender did i got it right?

Comment: are you mixing several images or animations? maybe edit your question and tell a bit more about what you're trying to do

Comment: I will be doing both, i want to first created the right compositing and settings for a still image render from maya, then i would like to just replace the image with an image sequence video/animation so it will have the same setting / effects